# Why does my use of NDB's `populate()` not accept `id` or `parent`, but only `key`?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, google-cloud-datastore

I want to create an entity object and after its construction, before writing it into the datastore, I want to set parent and id.

According to [App Engine docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_populate), the constructor accepts these keyword arguments:
- `id`
- `key`
- `parent`

> You cannot easily define a property named "key", "id", "parent", or
>   "namespace". If you pass, for example, key="foo" in a constructor or
>   populate() call, it sets the entity's key, not a property attribute
>   named "key".

For `populate()`, it says it would accept the same keyword arguments as the constructor. However, it seems I'm doing something wrong, because the only keyword argument that works is `key`. Using `id` and/or `parent` gives me errors.

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    pass

foo = Foo()
foo.populate(key=ndb.Key('Bar', 1, 'Foo', 123))
foo.key == ndb.Key('Bar', 1, 'Foo', 123)  # True
```

When instead I use the keyword `parent`...

```
f.populate(parent=ndb.Key('Bar', 1))
```

...I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2960, in _populate
    self._set_attributes(kwds)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2970, in _set_attributes
    prop = getattr(cls, name)  # Raises AttributeError for unknown properties.
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'parent'
```

or sometimes this (not sure what makes the difference):

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2960, in _populate
    self._set_attributes(kwds)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2972, in _set_attributes
    raise TypeError('Cannot set non-property %s' % name)
TypeError: Cannot set non-property parent
```

If I use `id`...

```
f.populate(id=123)
```

I get again an attribute error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2960, in _populate
    self._set_attributes(kwds)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model.py", line 2970, in _set_attributes
    prop = getattr(cls, name)  # Raises AttributeError for unknown properties.
AttributeError: type object 'Foo' has no attribute 'id'
```

Shouldn't all of my `populate()` examples above work with any of the keyword arguments?

I know, I could only use `key` to achieve the same as with `parent` and `id` together, but I would like to know what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`parent` is a property of a `Key` when using ancestor paths. The constructor accepts it as a convenience but since it is not its own property, `populate()` will complain that it does not exist. Same goes for `id`. The constructor uses `id` to construct a `Key` using `_get_kind()` and the value of `id`.

An example is worth 1000 comments. See how `id` and `parent` are used to construct a `key`

```
>>> from google.appengine.ext import ndb
>>>>
>>> class Foo(ndb.Model):
...     pass
...
>>> foo = Foo(id=123, parent=ndb.Key('Bar', 1))
>>> foo.key
Key('Bar', 1, 'Foo', 123)
>>> foo.id
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'id'
>>> foo.parent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'parent'
```

Answer (score 2):

The docs may not be clear enough on this issue, but you're only supposed to use `populate` to update properties of the model (actual data).

This is clear looking at the source code, for example [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L2862) of the model constructor:

> Note: you cannot define a property named key; the .key attribute always refers to the entity's key.  But you can define properties named id or parent.  Values for the latter cannot be passed through the constructor, but can be assigned to entity attributes after the entity has been created.

Suggesting we could use `id` and `parent` as properties/attributes, thus `populate` calls will try to set them.

It gets even clearer once we get to the `populate` [implementation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L2917), where the inline documentation has a provision for your exact question:

> Each keyword argument will be used to set a corresponding property.  Keywords must refer to valid property name.  This is similar to passing keyword arguments to the Model constructor, except that no provisions for key, id or parent are made.

Maybe the docs should be updated with this information to avoid the confusion. I never ran into this issue myself, maybe because I've been following the recommendation of "only setting the key when instantiating a model", however I can't find a quote for this statement; I take it as a rule of thumb, and am under the impression that trying to assign it afterwards should raise exceptions everywhere.

And as if the previous references weren't enough, look at [this line](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/model.py#L2886) in the constructor:

```
self._key = _validate_key(key, entity=self)
```

You won't find that anywhere else, so this is the only instance of a key being assigned [properly] to a model (as you can imagine, `populate` only iterates and sets values).